# mysql join two tables, count and sum alias

Tags: php, mysql

I have query

```
SELECT p. * , COUNT( r.poll_option_id ) AS voteCount
FROM poll_options AS p
LEFT JOIN poll_responses AS r ON ( r.poll_option_id = p.id ) 
WHERE p.poll_id =1
GROUP BY p.id
LIMIT 0 , 30
```

It returns me this data which is correct

```
 id poll_id caption voteCount   
 1  1   32  1
 2  1   256 1
 3  1   512 0
```

Now I need to count that alias voteCount, so for this example it would be 1+1+0=2.. And return it as another alias. How could I do it? I must use only 1 query, and I do not have rights to edit database. I have tried examples from 
[MySQL Join two tables count and sum from second table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15387808/mysql-join-two-tables-count-and-sum-from-second-table) 
[MySQL query, COUNT and SUM with two joined tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16281892/mysql-query-count-and-sum-with-two-joined-tables)
and couple more
but no luck..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a cross join to your same query by calculation sum of the count column

```
SELECT t1.*,t2.totalvoteCount FROM (
SELECT p. * , COUNT( r.poll_option_id ) AS voteCount
FROM poll_options AS p
LEFT JOIN poll_responses AS r ON ( r.poll_option_id = p.id ) 
WHERE p.poll_id =1
GROUP BY p.id
LIMIT 0 , 30
) t1
CROSS JOIN (
SELECT SUM(voteCount) totalvoteCount
FROM (
SELECT  p.id,COUNT( r.poll_option_id ) AS voteCount
FROM poll_options AS p
LEFT JOIN poll_responses AS r ON ( r.poll_option_id = p.id ) 
WHERE p.poll_id =1
GROUP BY p.id
LIMIT 0 , 30
) t
) t2
```

Output would be as follows

```
id poll_id caption voteCount   totalvoteCount 
 1  1       32          1        2
 2  1       256         1        2
 3  1       512         0        2
```

Answer (score 1):

Wrap another query around it?

```
SELECT id, poll_id, SUM(voteCount) AS votecount
FROM ( ... your query here ... ) As subquery
GROUP BY poll_id
```

Comment: Thanks this works but I need to get other results too. I have accepted M Khalid Junaid answer as it's perfect for me.

Answer (score 1):

In your example `voteCount` represents the count for each group. If you want the count across all groups then you can omit the `group by` clause (which is legal if your select only consists of a `count`).

```
SELECT COUNT(r.poll_option_id)
FROM poll_options AS p
LEFT JOIN poll_responses AS r ON (r.poll_option_id = p.id)
WHERE p.poll_id =1
```

Or

```
SELECT p. * , COUNT( r.poll_option_id ) AS voteCount,
    (SELECT COUNT(r.poll_option_id)
    FROM poll_options AS p
    LEFT JOIN poll_responses AS r ON (r.poll_option_id = p.id)
    WHERE p.poll_id =1) totalVoteCount
FROM poll_options AS p
LEFT JOIN poll_responses AS r ON ( r.poll_option_id = p.id ) 
WHERE p.poll_id =1
GROUP BY p.id
LIMIT 0 , 30
```